# Szemerédi's Degree Regularity Lemma

Tags: graph-theory

Does anyone know where I can find a nice clean proof of the Szemerédi's Degree Regularity Lemma that is similar to follow of the original Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma that is not a PDF of hundreds of pages?

Comment: Check out chapter 7 "Extremal graph theory" of the online version of the book "Graph Theory", 4th edition, at http://diestel-graph-theory.com/

Comment: That just deals with the Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma not the degree form unless I am mistaken?

Comment: If the two are not the same thing, you are right, of course. Good luck.

Comment: They follow the same flavor, but are not the same I have looked through Diestal, Bollabas and West's proofs.